# How can i make an object jump using Cannon.js + Three.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, cannon.js

While searching for this solution, I noticed many used,
cannonBody.velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY

But in my case, It works while the object is already in motion but not once it became stationary. So, I was wondering if there are a few conditions to be met for it to jump.

I would also encourage a demo snippet of making a simple object (a ball) to jump when the spacebar is pressed.

Comment: Please update your answer with any attempt you made at this. Have a look here if you need help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I switched to OimoPhysics and things woke up properly. It uses the same conventions. How it replaces the physics world in a declarative setup, I don't know..? I've done that with Canon, where you set the config tolerance. But even with the quick setup where you just add a body or move it, Oimo solved the sleep problem immediately. ApplyForce would be more consistent and realistic than an arbitrary + y value. I think applyForce would give less problems.

It's easy to forget to call update on the physics after you move the geometry. If the render loop misses a step your geometry may be frozen, lost to the physics body. Or if you add another physics body in its place the original pointer may be lost. Then if another body collides it will suddenly wake up. It depends on the circumstances and the version...

Comment: Oh thanks, But I want to implement this with Cannon.js. And the problem persists even with applyForce and applyImpulse

Comment: Well it could be buggy code, the mass, a global setting. There is a way to wake a sleeping body.

Comment: How to wake up a sleeping body? And the object is moving fine when I apply "world.allowSleep = false", But will this cause any performance issues or anything? And thanks cause I realized this only after going through your response

Comment: https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js/blob/569730f94a1d9da47967a24fad0323ef7d5b4119/demos/sleep.html#L53

Comment: Sleep improves performance. If you have 1 kinetic ball it may not matter. Test your settings (especially collisions) to understand broadphase sleep. Kinetic objects still use memory if they fall off the world edge or screen.

Comment: anyone knows where i can get a good tutorial on Cannon.js

Comment: There are some great code examples at https://github.com/lo-th/Oimo.js and https://github.com/saharan/OimoPhysics. These are the better examples related to understanding.